# MySQL - select just the highest count from each different column type

Tags: mysql

Suppose you have a table like this:

`id user score`

It's a dump of user scores, where each `user` can have N `score`'s.

How do you select the highest score for each user?

Comment: So, is `score` a list of scores, or does each row have a separate score and duplicate users?

Comment: What query have you tried so far? Can you please post the table structure as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT user,max(score) 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: you beat me. your answer looks familiar.

Comment: i took less time 'cause my answer is shorter and without order by :)

Comment: early bird gets the checkmark! but voted up for both of you ;) thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
select user, max(score) as HighScore
from table
group by user
order by max(score);
```

That should get you what you need.

**EDIT:**
Added statement terminator

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user, MAX(score) FROM [TABLE] GROUP BY user
```

Comment: `*` wont work here because 1) the query should fail since id, score are not in the `group by` list and 2) once put in the list, it'll aggregate on each score, effectively returning every row in the table with the additional field of `max(score)` which will = `score`.

Answer (score -1):

An alternate to MAX(score) is to use PHP to iterate through the score list and pick the highest.

```
while ( $curUser = mysql_fetch_assoc($userQry) ) {
    $highest = 0;
    $scores = explode(',',$curUser["score"]);
    foreach($scores as $score){
        if ($highest < $score)
        $highest = $score;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing something about the overhead that this would generate on the application relative to just using the DBMS.

Comment: If the table was set up with `score` as a list of scores, this would be a good option regardless of overhead. for example: `id=1 user=5 score="15,20,35,75"`. MAX wouldn't work in this case, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: I see where you're coming from. I don't think that's the data model in practice in this situation, at least that's not the impression that I get. Additionally, I'm not sure it's the best option given the technology in use.

Comment: Likely not, after reading it again. I was interpreting "where each user can have N score's." as this type of list instead of one score per id. Oh well, maybe this post will help someone else in the future. I ran into a similar problem not too long ago myself which made me think of it haha